# How to use printStream

Tags: java

I have created a few methods to edit text from a file word by word but now need to use printStream to create a new file with the updated text. I have done some research on printStream but still don't quite understand how to do this. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File jaws = new File("JawsScript.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(jaws);


        while (in.hasNext()) {
    String word = in.next();

        PrintStream out =
    new PrintStream(new File("stuff.txt"));

    System.out.println(convert(word));

    }
```

The method "convert" is a method that calls all of the other methods and applies all of the changes to a single string in the text:

```
//Applies all of the methods to the string
public static String convert(String s) {
  String result = "";
    result = rYah(s);
    result = rWah(result);
    result = transform(result);
    result = apend(result);
    result = replace(result);

    return result;
}
```

I basically am just wondering how I can use printStream to apply "convert" to the text and print the updated text to a new file.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't reinitialize the PrintStream object in every loop iteration.

To write to a file, simply call PrintStream's `println` method. You may not realise it, but when you print to the console, this is exactly what you are doing. `System.out` is a PrintStream object.

```
PrintStream out =
    new PrintStream(new File("stuff.txt"));
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String word = in.next();
    out.println(convert(word));
}
```

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. However when I use this code, nothing gets printed at all. I know PrintStream creates a new file so I'm assuming I have to call that somehow?

Comment: No. The first line I gave makes the file. Nothing is printed to the console because your aren't telling it to print anything to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main2{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String str = " The Big House is";
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
        ps.printf("My name is : %s White", str);
        ps.flush();
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Output is : 
The Big House is White

The other way  to use PrintStream is...

```
        CharSequence cq = "The Big House is White";
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
        ps.append(cq);
        ps.flush();
        ps.close();
    }
}
```